# How to get all possible interpretations in regex match?

Tags: python, regex, re2

If `"Who acted as (?P<role>.*) in (?P<movie>.*)"` is the template 
I want to match for queries like `"Who acted as tony montana in Scarface"`.

If the role name has a "in" here or If the movie name has an "in", the regex match will go wrong.

Eg: `"Who acted as k in men in black" will give "k in men" as role.`

May be a non greedy approach will work for this query but it will go for a toss if the movie contains the word "in".
How do I get all possible interpretations here?

Comment: `Who acted as (?P<role>.*?) in (?P<movie>.*)` works for your input.

Comment: This isn't a regex-writing service; have a go at modifying it yourself: http://regex101.com/r/uD0yR9/1

Comment: Well, formally, `Who acted as man in elevator in women in red` has three possible interpretations. I don't think this is solvable using only regexes.

Comment: @georg: Thank you for getting my problem statement correctly. Is there any clever implementation in python that will backpropagate and find all interpretations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a phrase like `'a in b in c in d'` this will generate all possible partitions by the word `in`:

```
words = phrase.split()

for n, w in enumerate(words):
    if w == 'in':
        print '(%s) in (%s) ' % (
            ' '.join(words[:n]),
            ' '.join(words[n+1:]))
```

For your specific problem, if there are three `in`s in the phrase, the "middle" interpretation (`(a in b) in (c in d)`) would be most probably correct, but with two `in`s there's no way to solve this by the means of text manipulations, because "left" and "right" partitions are equally probable, consider:

```
Who acted as jeebs in men in black
Who acted as woman in red in matrix
```

You'll have to use NLP or database-driven methods to parse this correctly.